# How to monitor windows service and process with zabbix

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I am new in Zabbix and I am using Zabbix 3.4 version. I have installed server on Linux and want to monitor and check status of Windows service using its Windows agent.
I got the status of services using the key below

```
service.info[<serviceName>,state]
```

It returns me proper status of service. Now I want to check how much CPU is utilized by process and how much memory is utilized by process.
I tried some of keys but it's not returning proper value.

```
perf_counter[\Process(<processName>)\% User Time]   // to get CPU utilization by process
proc_info[<processName>,wkset] // to get memory utilize by process
system.cpu.util[,system,avg5]  // to get total CPU utilization
vm.memory.size[available]   // to get total RAM utilization
```

But none of above working properly. I tried other keys also but agent logs say it's unsupported. I checked forum and searched on Google but nothing found.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there isn't a direct match Windows Service -> Specific process.
Any service spawns N processes for its internals and also can spawn additional processes to manage incoming connection, log requests and so on.

Think about a classic httpd server: you should find at least one master process, various pre-forked server processes and php/php-fpm processes for current requests.

Regarding the keys you provided, what do you mean by "not working properly" ?

You can refer to Zabbix [documentation for Windows-specific items](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent/win_keys) for the exact syntax of the items and the meaning of the return values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Zabbix item for CPU Utilization of average 5 min:

```
system.cpu.util[,,avg5]
```

This will give you average usage of CPU per 5 mins on Windows server. You can then create an appropriate trigger for the same.